# Cheapest way to get HON circle status?

Tags: star-alliance, loyalty-programs

I'm looking for the absolute cheapest way to get the Star Alliance [HON circle status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_&_More#HON_Circle_status). For that you have to collect 600,000 status miles in two calendar years. I don't care about long layovers or a lot of different stops. I also do not want to visit the countries I travel to, but just get this status.

Comment: The mean distance from the Earth to the moon is 238,900 miles, so a roundtrip will get you to 477,800 miles. The remaining 122,200 miles should be relatively easy to find.

Comment: HON Circle is specific to Lufthansa's Miles and More program, it's not a Star Alliance status.

Comment: With the recent changes announced in the M&M program in 2020, this question along with the answers will have to be revised, as the cheapest way to get HON Circle status on mileage runs is not dependent anymore on fare classes. Being a HON Circle myself through work, I often question myself who would really go waste so much time and money flying to get a status that is less and less valuable these days. My average spending has been 150k - 250k USD per year. It supposedly can be done for 40k - 50k USD with C/D fare flights averaging 6.5 to 8.5 CPM. This is without other expenses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say your question is best suited for the gurus over at [Flyertalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/miles-more-lufthansa-austrian-swiss-other-partners-495/), who specialize in wrangling frequent flyer miles and the like.  Take a look at the Miles and More forum, as well as the mileage run forum (which is their term for taking special trips that maximize mileage earned for minimum cost).

However, if you're willing to settle for slightly less status (no first class terminals in Germany, for instance) consider obtaining Star Alliance gold status on Aegean Airlines for significantly less cost—only 20,000 miles if I remember correctly.  This will allow you priority boarding, lounge access, luggage tags, etc. for less than $1000 in flights if you plan it correctly. Look at [this thread on Flyertalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/aegean-airlines-miles-bonus/1308205-aegean-gold-card-crash-course-new-a3-read.html) for more.

Comment: It should be noted that since November 2014, this answer is outdated - Aegean doesn't give away status that easily anymore.

Answer (score 13):

To get the HON Circle Status there is only one way: flying, flying, flying.  As of this September only flights in Business and First Class will earn you HON Circle Miles and keep in mind: you have to fly with Lufthansa, Swiss, Austrian or their affiliated companies (Star Alliance other than that doesn't count).
Check out the program at http://www.miles-and-more.com/online/portal/mam/de/program/information?nodeid=2536038&l=de&cid=18002